# org.testng.annotations.Configuration cannot be resolved

Tags: java, testng

I have upgraded from testng 6.3.1 to 6.14.2 and after this I am getting error on org.testng.annotations.Configuration as the class does not exist.
I just want to know how to replace this?.I have checked the deprecated API and found that this is deprecated in 6.9.x.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TLDR;** Use the [dedicated annotations](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotations) instead, eg: `@BeforeTest` instead of `@Configuration(beforeTest = true)`.

---

TBH I never used it, I've always used [the dedicated `@BeforeTest`, `@AfterTest`](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotations), etc annotations, but out of curiosity I've done a bit of research:

- according to the [change log](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/blob/master/CHANGES.txt#L1129) (currently line 1129) it's been deprecated since v 5.0 of 2009/04/01: *Added: Deprecated `@Configuration and` introduced `@BeforeSuite/Test/Class/TestMethod`*
- it's been removed with [this commit](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/commit/c5b3c1eac15a28339ba52020cce2513e25586e5e)
- before its removal (up to v6.11) it's javadoc read:

  > Configuration information for a TestNG class.
  >   **Deprecated.**
  >   Use `@BeforeSuite`, `@AfterSuite`, `@BeforeTest`, `@AfterTest`, `@BeforeGroups`, `@AfterGroups`, `@BeforeClass`, `@AfterClass`, `@BeforeMethod`, `@AfterMethod`
- [usage samples](https://www.javatips.net/api/org.testng.annotations.configuration):

```java
    @Configuration(beforeTest = true)
    public void setUp() {
        ...
```

In conclusion, just use the [newer individual annotations](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotations) instead.